# echo abc | ruby -p -e "sub('a','A').sub('b', 'B')": why not "ABc"?

Tags: ruby

I understand the following:

```
$ ruby -e "p 'abc'.sub('a','A').sub('b', 'B')"
"ABc"
```

I am OK with the following also:

```
echo abc | ruby -p -e "sub('a','A');sub('b', 'B')"
ABc
```

But:

```
echo abc | ruby -p -e "sub('a','A').sub('b', 'B')"
Abc
```

I expect the result to be "ABc" as well, why is it not? The second `sub('b', 'B')` is not operational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two cases look similar, but in fact you are running different methods from the Ruby core library in them:

In your first case, i.e. `sub('a','A');sub('b', 'B')`:

You are running both `sub` without specifying an explicit receiver, and therefore you are invoking the method [`Kernel#sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#sub-method). The Ruby-Doc says about this method:

> ###### `sub(pattern, replacement)` → `$_`
>
> Equivalent to `$_.sub(args)`, except that `$_` will be updated if substitution occurs. Available only when -p/-n command line option specified.

The following examples illustrate the differences with and without a receiver:

```
$ echo abc | ruby -p -e '$_.sub("a","A").sub("b", "B"); $_'
abc

$ echo abc | ruby -p -e 'sub("a","A").sub("b", "B"); $_'
Abc
```

Hence, in the first example, you really invoke that `Kernel#sub` twice, and after each invocation, `$_` is updated. Therefore, `$_` is *ABc* after the second `sub` has been executed. At the end of the of the whole expression supplied by `-e` (i.e. at the end of the implicit loop provided by the `-p` option), the value of `$_` is printed, and you see *ABc*.

In your second example, i.e.

```
sub('a','A').sub('b', 'B')
```

The first `sub` again is `Kernel#sub`, as before. It has the effect of turning the string into *Abc*, and also sets `$_` to *Abc*. However, the second `sub` now does have an explicit receiver (the string resulting from the first `sub`), and in this case, the method [`String#sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#sub-method) is executed. This method produces *ABc*, but different to `Kernel#sub`, it does **not** update `$_`. Therefore, `$_` is still set to *Abc*, and this is what you see as output.

While it seems to be convenient to rely on the implicit effect certain methods have on `$_`, it is sometimes easier to make the manipulation explicit. For instance, if you do a

```
$_=$_.sub('a','A').sub('b','B')
```

you can clearly see what is going on. An alternative would be

```
$_.sub!('a','A');$_.sub!('b','B')
```

Note that in the last case, you do **not** want to chain the two `sub!`, because String#sub! returns `nil` if no substitutions have been performed.

Comment: If you want to show a literal underscore, escape it: `$\_` → $\_. Otherwise Markdown will interpret it as a delimiter for italic text.

Comment: There are multiple occurrences of `$_` in your answer. It'd be a better idea to use code formatting for them.

Comment: I think I caught now all of them .....